# How to use jQuery 1.6.2 with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am trying to require jQuery as a dependency but I only get an error when I try to do so. I know 1.6.2 is old but I need it to not break some other code. It worked when I used 1.8.2 but I had to shift back to an older version.

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function app.js:46
>
> (anonymous function) main.js:46   context.execCb require.min.js:1603 Module.check
> require.min.js:845 (anonymous function)   require.min.js:1087
> (anonymous function) require.min.js:130 (anonymous function)
> require.min.js:1130 each require.min.js:58 Module.emit
> require.min.js:1129 Module.check   require.min.js:899 (anonymous
> function) require.min.js:1087 (anonymous function)
> require.min.js:130 (anonymous function) require.min.js:1130 each
> require.min.js:58 Module.emit   require.min.js:1129 Module.check
> require.min.js:899 Module.enable require.min.js:1117   Module.init
> require.min.js:758 callGetModule require.min.js:1144
> context.completeLoad   require.min.js:1517 context.onScriptLoad
> require.min.js:1624

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any exemple code, how you are booting up your things and all it is very hard to help. I will give you a general answer and hope it helps you out, or keep you busy while waiting for other answers. :) Best of luck.

From http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2287-Using-jQuery-As-A-Named-Module-In-RequireJS.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Loading jQuery As A Named Module In RequireJS</title>

<!-- Include the require JS library. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


// Configure the RequireJS paths to use an alias for the
// jQuery library.
require.config({
paths: {
"jquery": "./jquery-1.6.4"
}
});


// Now that we have configured a named alias for the jQuery
// library, let's try to load it using the named module.
require(
[
"jquery"
],
function( $164 ){

// Log the callback parameter.
console.log( "$164.fn.jquery:", $164.fn.jquery );

}
);


</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Left intentionally blank. -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is how I do it, but I have only `$` as a parameter, not `$164`. Does a single dollar character ruin it?

Comment: not suposed to, I am also using $ in my require. $164 was just to remind the version in the exemple.

Comment: Please add details. Maybe a sample code that reproduces your config? Just enough to recreate the problem so I can work on something...